# Cinnamon and QxtGlobalShortcut

Tags: qt5, cinnamon

I have a Qt5 Application, in which I have defined a `QxtGlobalShortcut` object. This program works as expected in KDE4 or Plasma5. However, when I run this application in Cinnamon, the global keybindings do not work.

Another application written in Qt4 which contains `QxtGlobalShortcut` object works properly in both KDE/Plasma and Cinnamon.

Any ideas as to what the problem could be?

I'm using debian testing.
Qt4 Version: 4.8.7
Qt5 Version: 5.6.1

`QxtGlobalShortcut` class is compiled from source. The same source is being used in both Qt4 and Qt5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same issues. Sometimes global shortcut events are not caught if the application has no windows. Workaround is to create [invisible dummy window](https://github.com/hluk/qxtglobalshortcut/blob/79648867167f5b1a8ce344279cb74f0e5360ecf5/src/qxtglobalshortcut_x11.cpp#L54).

Since [Qxt in no longer maintained](https://bitbucket.org/libqxt/libqxt/wiki/Home), I've created [repository with some additional fixes](https://github.com/hluk/qxtglobalshortcut) (pull requests are welcome). This can be built as separate library.